# Twilio Verify Python SDK throws 404 error

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, twilio-python

I am using Twilio Python SDK for verify services. I get below error when I try to send email OTPs.

```
{TwilioRestException}HTTP 404 error: Unable to create record: The requested resource 
/Services/VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Verifications was not found
```

Below is my Python code to perform this task:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
client = Client('ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', AUTH_TOKEN)
verification = self.client.verify.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')\
                .verifications\
                .create(to='example@gmail.com', channel='email')
```

When I use CURL to send request then it happens successfully and I receive the mail with the verify code.

```
curl -X POST https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Verifications \
--data-urlencode "To=example@gmail.com" \
--data-urlencode "Channel=email" \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:your_auth_token
```

The above POST call in POSTMAN gives me the below URL:

```
https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Verifications/VEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

when I click on that URL that same error is thrown up as it was shown from Python SDK.

Note: But from POSTMAN I am getting receiving Email but not from Python SDK.

Why am I getting the above mentioned error in Python, even after following the steps of DOCS.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/email?code-sample=code-check-an-email-verification&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x#create-a-sendgrid-api-key

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I have done the same few hours ago, still I didn't got any response from Stack Overflow team so flagged again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We spoke privately about this question. It turned out that Vijay was using the Twilio Python library version 6.20.0.

I recommended upgrading to [the latest version of Twilio Python, 6.41.0](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) (as I write this), and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure you are running a more recent version of the [Python SDK](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/CHANGES.md).